# What are channels used for?

Tags: go, channel

When looking through some Go code I found the following:

```
  ch := make(chan int)
```

I looked up in a online tutorial how Go Channels work:

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2

But I find this example unclear.

Can someone give me a easy explanation and an example of the use of channels?

Comment: check this article: [How does golang channel works](https://jerryan.medium.com/how-does-golang-channel-works-6d66acd54753)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**chan** is a channel in Golang. In simple word you can think it as a box in which you put a item at one end and then pick it from other end.

**Unbuffered Channels**

[image]

**Buffered Channel**

[image]

This is the small code I have written for you to understand channels. Now change order of go routines and see the outputs. Each time output may differ.

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
    )

    func main() {
        messages := make(chan int)
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
            messages <- 1
        }()
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
            messages <- 2
        }() 
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            messages <- 3
        }()
        go func() {
            for i := range messages {
                fmt.Println(i)
            }
        }()
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            messages <- 4
        }()
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
            messages <- 5
        }()
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    }
```

For best understanding visit this blog where go routines and channels are described in GUI.

Visit http://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/

Comment: I love the illustrations!

Comment: This was a huge help! Thank you very much

Comment: _"order does not matter"_ – this is not true. The Go spec states that: _"Channels act as first-in-first-out queues."_

Answer (score 55):

I think the spec is pretty clear on this. [Spec: Channel types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types)

> A channel provides a mechanism for [concurrently executing functions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Go_statements) to communicate by [sending](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements) and [receiving](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) values of a specified element type.

When you have multiple goroutines which are executed concurrently, channels provide the easiest way to allow the goroutines to communicate with each other.

One way for communication would be via a "shared" variable which is visible to both goroutines, but that would require proper locking / synchronized access.

Instead, Go favors channels. Quoting from [Effective Go: Share by communicating](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#sharing):

> Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating.

So instead of putting messages into a shared slice for example, you can create a channel (visible to both goroutines), and without any external synchronization / locking, one goroutine can send messages (values) via the channel, and the other goroutine can receive them.

> Only one goroutine has access to the value at any given time. Data races cannot occur, by design.

So in fact, any number of goroutines can send values on the same channel, and any number of goroutines can receive values from it, still without any further synchronization. See related question for more details: [If I am using channels properly should I need to use mutexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039229/if-i-am-using-channels-properly-should-i-need-to-use-mutexes)

#### Channel example

Let's see an example where we start 2 additional goroutines for concurrent computation purposes. We pass a number to the first, which adds 1 to it, and delivers the result on a 2nd channel. The 2nd goroutine will receive a number, multiply it by 10 and deliver it to the result channel:

```
func AddOne(ch chan<- int, i int) {
    i++
    ch <- i
}

func MulBy10(ch <-chan int, resch chan<- int) {
    i := <-ch
    i *= 10
    resch <- i
}
```

This is how it can be called / used:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    resch := make(chan int)

    go AddOne(ch, 9)
    go MulBy10(ch, resch)

    result := <-resch
    fmt.Println("Result:", result)
}
```

Communicating via channels also takes care of goroutines waiting for each other. In this example it means `MulBy10()` will wait until `AddOne()` delivers the incremented number, and `main()` will wait for `MulBy10()` before printing the result. Output as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RuTvpkee4v)):

```
Result: 100
```

#### Language support

There are a number of language constructs which are for easy use of channels, for example:

- The `for ... range` on a channel loops over values received from a channel, until the channel is closed.
- The [`select`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements) statement can be used to list multiple channel operations such as *send on a channel* and *receive from a channel*, and the one that can proceed without blocking will be selected (randomly if there are multiple ones that can proceed; and will block if none is ready).
- There is a special form of the receive operator which allows you to check if the channel was closed (besides receiving a value): `v, ok := <-ch`
- The builtin [`len()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) function tells the number of elements queued (unread); the builting [`cap()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#cap) function returns the channel buffer capacity.

#### Other uses

For a more practical example, see how channels can be used to implement a [worker pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38172204/1705598). A similar use is distributing values from a [producer to consumer(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34466755/1705598).

Another practical example is to implement a [memory pool using buffered channels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38506367/1705598).

And yet another practical example is [an elegant implementation of a broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417199/how-to-broadcast-message-using-channel/49877632#49877632).

A channel is often used to timeout some blocking operation, utilizing a channel returned by [`time.After()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After) which "fires" after the specified delay / duration ("fires" means a value will be sent on it). See this example for demonstration (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QHveRuk6OI)):

```
ch := make(chan int)

select {
case i := <-ch:
    fmt.Println("Received:", i)
case <-time.After(time.Second):
    fmt.Println("Timeout, no value received")
}
```

It can be used to wait for a maximum time amount for some value, but if other goroutines cannot supply the value by that time, we may decide to do something else instead.

Also a special form of communication may be just to signal completion of some operation (without actually sending any "useful" data). Such case may be implemented by a channel with any element type, e.g. `chan int`, and sending any value on it, e.g. `0`. But since the sent value holds no information, you may declare it like `chan struct{}`. Or even better, if you only need a one-time signalling, you may just close the channel which can be intercepted on the other side using `for ... range`, or receiving from it (as receiving from a closed channel proceeds immediately, yielding the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the element type). Also know that even though a channel may be used for this kind of signalling, there's a better alternative for this: [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup).

#### Further reading

It's worth knowing about the channel axioms to avoid suprising behaviour: [How does a non initialized channel behave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015602/how-does-a-non-initialized-channel-behave)

[The Go Blog: Share Memory By Communicating](https://blog.golang.org/share-memory-by-communicating)

[The Go Blog: Go Concurrency Patterns: Pipelines and cancellation](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines)

[The Go Blog: Advanced Go Concurrency Patterns](https://blog.golang.org/advanced-go-concurrency-patterns)

[Ardan labs: The Nature Of Channels In Go](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2014/02/the-nature-of-channels-in-go.html)

Comment: I love this answer, especially the bit about using time.After(time.Second). I didn't know that could be done.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is very similar to something that's been in Unix/Linux since the beginning:  *pipes.*

These are a reliable inter-process / inter-thread communication facility that is built-in to the language.  Very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Use channels if you want goroutines to signal each other. There are multiple reasons you might want to want this signalling.

1. Signal another goroutine to start their task.
2. Wait for the other goroutine to end their task.
3. Signal other goroutines to stop their work by closing the channel.
   There are other such scenarios you can find here. https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/10/the-behavior-of-channels.html

Use channels if you want goroutines to communicate. This could be with or without data.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

/*
  Simulation for sending messages from threads for processing,
  and getting a response (processing result) to the thread
*/
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type (
    TMsg struct { // message
        name   string // thread name, owner name
        backId int    // index of response Back channel, or -1
        msg    string // message
        note   string // comment
    }

    TTh struct { // for thread
        name   string // thread name
        jobId  int    // index of central Job chanel
        backId int    // index of response Back channel, or -1
    }

    TChans map[int]chan TMsg
)

var gChans TChans //global variable, all channels map

func main() {
    gChans = make(TChans)      // all channels map
    jobIndex, job := NewChan() // chanel for send mesage to central Job (from threads)
    _, worker := NewChan()     // channel for send message to Worker (from Job receiver)

    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ { // 5 threads
        backIndex, _ := NewChan()                                                    // channel index for response back the thread
        go ping(TTh{name: fmt.Sprint(i) + "th", jobId: jobIndex, backId: backIndex}) //start threads
    }

    //go Job(job, worker) // central receiver and start workers
    Job(job, worker) // central receiver and start workers

    for LenChan() > 2 { // 2 = job and worker channels
        SleepM(5000)
    }
}

func Job(job, worker chan TMsg) { //central receiver
    var v TMsg
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancelWorkers := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ { // start workers , sql simulation
        go Worker(i, worker, ctx)
    }
    for {
        select {
        case v = <-job: // receive message
            if v.note == "sql" { // sql simulation
                worker <- v
            } else {
                if v.note == "end" {
                    FreeChan(v.backId)
                    fmt.Println(v.name, "FREE")
                } else {
                    ch := GetChan(v.backId)
                    if ch != nil {
                        ch <- TMsg{name: v.name, backId: v.backId, msg: v.msg, note: "receiver"}
                    }
                }
            }
        default:
            if LenChan() <= 2 {
                cancelWorkers() // cancel workers
                return
            } else {
                SleepM(2)
            }
        }
    }
}

func Worker(id int, worker <-chan TMsg, ctx context.Context) { // simulate sql or auther process
    var v TMsg
    for {
        select {
        case v = <-worker:
            {
                SleepM(rand.Intn(50))
                v.note = "worker:" + fmt.Sprint(id)
                ch := GetChan(v.backId)
                if ch != nil {
                    ch <- v
                }
            }
        case <-ctx.Done(): //return
        default:
            {
                //fmt.Println("worker", id)
                SleepM(2)
            }
        }
    }
}

func waitResponse(d chan TMsg, pTimeout int) (bool, TMsg) {
    var v TMsg
    for {
        select {
        case v = <-d:
            return true, v
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(pTimeout) * time.Second):
            return false, v
        }
    }
}

func ping(pTh TTh) {
    SleepM(10)
    var v TMsg
    ok := true
    i := 0
    job := GetChan(pTh.jobId)   // central Job receiver chanel
    back := GetChan(pTh.backId) // response Back channel
    for i < 50 {
        if ok {
            ok = false
            job <- TMsg{name: pTh.name, backId: pTh.backId, msg: fmt.Sprint(i), note: "sql"}
            i++
        }
        if back != nil {
            if !ok {
                ok, v = waitResponse(back, 10) //with timeout 10 sec
                if ok {
                    fmt.Println(v.name, "msg:", v.msg, v.note)
                    SleepM(1)
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(pTh.name, "response timeout")
                }

            }
        } else {
            SleepM(1)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(v.name, "---- end ----")
    v.note = "end"
    job <- v
}

func NewChan() (int, chan TMsg) {
    mux := &sync.RWMutex{}
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()
    index := len(gChans)
    gChans[index] = make(chan TMsg)
    return index, gChans[index]
}

func GetChan(pIndex int) chan TMsg {
    mux := &sync.RWMutex{}
    mux.Lock()
    defer mux.Unlock()
    ch, ok := gChans[pIndex]
    if ok {
        return ch
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func LenChan() int {
    return len(gChans)
}

func FreeChan(pIndex int) bool {
    ch := GetChan(pIndex)
    if ch != nil {
        mux := &sync.RWMutex{}
        mux.Lock()
        defer mux.Unlock()
        close(gChans[pIndex]) //close channel
        gChans[pIndex] = nil
        delete(gChans, pIndex)
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func SleepM(pMilliSec int) { // sleep millisecounds
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(pMilliSec) * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).