# Golang cannot use as type struct array or slice literal

Tags: json, go, struct, slice, literals

I'm trying to write a function in Go that takes a JSON with URLs of a directory and perform BFS to find files in that directory. When I find a JSON that is a directory, the code makes a URL and should enqueue that URL. When I try to create the struct in the `append()` in the loop, I get errors.

```
type ContentResp []struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    ContentType string `json:"type"`
    DownloadURL string `json:"download_url"`
}
...

var contentResp ContentResp
search(contentQuery, &contentResp)

for _, cont := range contentResp {
        append(contentResp, ContentResp{Name:cont.Name, ContentType:"dir", DownloadURL:cont.contentDir.String()})
}

./bfs.go:129: undefined: Name
./bfs.go:129: cannot use cont.Name (type string) as type struct { Name string "json:\"name\""; ContentType string "json:\"type\""; DownloadURL string "json:\"download_url\"" } in array or slice literal
./bfs.go:129: undefined: ContentType
./bfs.go:129: cannot use "dir" (type string) as type struct { Name string "json:\"name\""; ContentType string "json:\"type\""; DownloadURL string "json:\"download_url\"" } in array or slice literal
./bfs.go:129: undefined: DownloadURL
./bfs.go:129: cannot use cont.contentDir.String() (type string) as type struct { Name string "json:\"name\""; ContentType string "json:\"type\""; DownloadURL string "json:\"download_url\"" } in array or slice literal
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ContentResp` type is a *slice*, not a struct, yet you're treating it as a struct when you use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) trying to create a value of it:

```
type ContentResp []struct {
    // ...
}
```

More precisely it's a slice of a type which is an anonymous struct. Creating values of anonymous structs are unpleasant, so instead you should create (name) a type being only the `struct`, and use a slice of this, e.g.:

```
type ContentResp struct {
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    ContentType string `json:"type"`
    DownloadURL string `json:"download_url"`
}

var contentResps []ContentResp
```

**Further issues:**

Let's examine this loop:

```
for _, cont := range contentResp {
    append(contentResp, ...)
}
```

The code above ranges over a slice, and inside it it tries to append elements to the slice. 2 issues with this: `append()` returns the result which must be stored (it might even have to allocate a new, bigger backing array and copy existing elements over, in which case the result slice will point to a completely different array and the old one should be abandoned). So it should be used like this:

```
    contentResps = append(contentResps, ...)
```

Second: you shouldn't change the slice you're ranging over. The `for ... range` evaluates the range expression *once* (at most), so you changing it (adding elements to it) will have no effect to the iterator code (it will not see the slice header changes).

If you have such a case where you have "tasks" to be completed, but during execution new tasks may arise (to be completed, recursively), a channel is a much better solution. See this answer to get a feeling of channels: [What are golang channels used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826692/what-are-golang-channels-used-for/39826883#39826883)